# Autocomplete in Popover Component with search rentention

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-props

I have a problem with saving the state of the search query.

[image: While typing]

[image: Console while typing]

When the popover is brought into focus, the searchString starts with undefined (second undefined value in picture). When the key 'b' is pressed, the event is fired, and it sets the value to "" (initialized value). As shown, when "bart" is in the search query, console only registers "bar". Does anyone know why this behavior occurs? The end goal is that I am trying to retain the search string on selection (it disappears onclick) -> would appreciate any help with this. The main code block where these changes are happening:

```
                <Autocomplete
                    open
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    multiple
                    classes={{
                        paper: classes.paper,
                        option: classes.option,
                        popperDisablePortal: classes.popperDisablePortal,
                    }}
                    value={pendingValue}
                    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                        setPendingValue(newValue);
                    }}
                    // inputValue={searchString}
                    // onInputChange={(event, newValue) => {
                    //     setSearchString(newValue);
                    // }}
                    disableCloseOnSelect
                    disablePortal
                    renderTags={() => null}
                    noOptionsText="No values"
                    renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <DoneIcon
                                className={classes.iconSelected}
                                style={{ visibility: selected ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}
                            />
                            <div className={classes.text}>
                                {option.value}
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                    options={[...suggestions].sort((a, b) => {
                        // Display the selected labels first.
                        let ai = selectedValue.indexOf(a);
                        ai = ai === -1 ? selectedValue.length + suggestions.indexOf(a) : ai;
                        let bi = selectedValue.indexOf(b);
                        bi = bi === -1 ? selectedValue.length + suggestions.indexOf(b) : bi;
                        return ai - bi;
                    })}
                    getOptionLabel={option => option.value}
                    renderInput={params => (
                        <InputBase
                            ref={params.InputProps.ref}
                            inputProps={params.inputProps}
                            autoFocus
                            className={classes.inputBase}
                            // onChange={(event) => {
                            //     console.log("event.target: ", event.target);
                            //     console.log("event.currentTarget: ", event.currentTarget);
                            //     setSearchString(event.currentTarget);
                            // }}
                            value={searchString}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    )}
                />
```

I have tried to store the value and re-populate it using both through the Autocomplete props and the InputBase (doing it on both causes it to crash). I have added a sandbox for your ref: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-feistel-qhdin)

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material UI autocomplete by design resets the search value every time you select an option. If you want to by pass it, use `useAutocomplete` hook to fine tune the component according to your need.

As for delayed console log values, you're setting the new value and then you're console logging the old value. So obviously it will print the old value, what else did you expect?

You code should have been like this

```js
    const handleInputChange = event => {
        // new value => event.currentTarget.value
        // old value => searchString
        // these values never mutate throughout this function call

        setSearchString(event.currentTarget.value);

        // searchString still remains the same here and 
        // won't change even if you call setState
        // it remains the same throughout this entire function call
        // Since Mutation is not allowed in Functional Programming
        // This is perhaps why Functional Programming is 
        // far better than Object Oriented Programming 

        console.log('searchString: ', event.currentTarget.value);
    }
```

However this isn't the right way to observe state changes. Better way would be something like this,

```js
// This will be called whenever React
// observes a change in anyState

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(anyState)
}, [anyState])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. I don't know that state would retain the old value within the function. I managed to print the updated value from the useEffect hook. I still used the original way to manage the state, simply because it would mean a substantial amount of rework for the rest of the component. Fixed the saving of search string as well, and updated the sandbox. Thanks a bunch!